# Xcode Archive Build Fails

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have an Xcode 7.2 project that succeeds when building/running against the local device *Product|Build*. The main project include a reference to InAppSettingsKit project. When I try *Product|Archive* the build fails. Any help or suggestions will appreciated.

[image]

The main project has a bridging header file to InAppSettingsKit project. The problem seems to be that the header file referenced in  the bridging header file is not found.

[image]

**Bridging Header File**

```
#ifndef Screen_Saver_Killer_InAppSettingsKit_Bridging_Header_h
#define Screen_Saver_Killer_InAppSettingsKit_Bridging_Header_h
#endif

#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKViewController.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKAppSettingsViewController.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSpecifierValuesViewController.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSpecifier.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSettingsReader.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

As requested, here is the **search paths** of the main project:
(I noticed InAppSettingsKit.xcodeproj is in red; does that mean anything ?)

[image]

Comment: Please provide screen shot of your build settings, especially Header Search Paths setting.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with InAppSettingsKit. Their website says: *for Archive builds there's a minor annoyance: To make those work, you'll need to add  **$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include**  to the  **HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS***

This wasn't quite right either.
I think this is a bug in XCode 7.2 + Swift with Obj-C dependencies when archives are built.
I now know way more about xcode than I ever wanted to.

First you need to go through the install logs to find out where things are being built. On my installation $OBJROOT points to:

/Users/jlongo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTX-*bmyyngijghtekdgqqfnabonhpuxo*/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJECTX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath

There I found the header files in the path:

```
.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/iphoneos/include/InAppSettingsKit/
```

So my resolution ended up being (non-recursive)

```
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include
```

Interestingly, $(OBJROOT) or other recursive paths shorter than this one did not work.

Also I placed this setting in:

```
Main Project|**Targets**|Build Settings|Header Search Paths
```

setting it here will not work:

```
  Main Project|**Project**|Build Settings|Header Search Paths
```